# existence of a cofiber sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

can anyone help me with this problem. thanx.

Show that there are cofiber sequence $S^{n+3} \to S^{n+2} \to \sum^{n}\mathbb{C}P^2$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Conclude that a space of the form $S^{n+2} \bigcup_{\alpha}D^{n+4}$ is homotopy equivalent to either$\sum^{n}\mathbb{C}P^2$ or $ S^{n+2} \vee  S^{n+4} $.

Hint: use the Steenrod operations. (Steenrod squares)

Comment: I'm totally lost here I have no idea how incorporate the sequence with the steenrod squares!!

Comment: There are two parts to the problem, though. Can you produce the sequence?

Comment: no, I don't see how $S^{n+3} \to S^{n+2} \to \sum^{n}\mathbb{C}P^2$ when $n=0$

Comment: if I can understand why$S^{2} \to S^{1} \to \mathbb{C}P^2$ then can I suspend the sequence till the n-th suspension

Comment: Hint for thE first part: what is the standard cell structure of $\mathbb CP^2$? Now take suspensions.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}P^2=S^2$ with a 4 cell wright?

Comment: Correct. And for the second part, if you want to bring steeenrod squares into the picture, you will have to generate cohomology groups. Since you already have a cofiber sequence , it makes sense to take hoomotopy classes of maps into an appropriate space.

Comment: Thanx for the help for part 1, but can you provide some more info about part 2.